Linear relations between minors of a matrix
Let $X = (x_{ij})_{1 \leq i, j \leq n}$ by an $n \times n$-matrix over the field $Q = \mathbf{F}(x_{ij})_{ij}$ for some field $\mathbf{F}$.
Let $[n] = \{1,\dotsc,n\}$.
For subsets $I, J \subseteq [n]$, let $X_{IJ}$ be the sub-matrix of $X$ with rows and columns indexed by $I$ and $J$.
For a $k \leq n$, the $k$th compound matrix of $X$ is the $\binom{n}{k} \times \binom{n}{k}$-matrix $\tilde{X} = (\det X_{IJ})_{I, J \in \binom{[n]}{k}}$.
For $K, L \subseteq \binom{[n]}{k}$, denote by $\tilde{X}_{KL}$ the submatrix of $\tilde{X}$ with rows and columns indexed by $K$ and $L$.
What can be said about linear dependence of columns of this matrix $\tilde{X}_{KL}$?
For example, if $n = 3$, $k = 2$, $K=\bigl\{\{1,3\}, \{1,3\}\bigr\}$ and $L = \binom{[n]}{k}$, then there is an identity
$$x_{33}\tilde{X}_{*;12} - x_{32}\tilde{X}_{*;13} + x_{31}\tilde{X}_{*;23} = 0,$$
where $* = \{13\}, \{2,3\}$.
Therefore, I get a linear relation among the columns of $\tilde{X}_{KL}$.
If course, this identity is a very special case.
Are there other, similar $Q$-linear relations? And is an exhaustive list known?
